# Assign values to multi-level columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array, multi-index

How should I assign values to a pandas dataframe with multi-level columns?

After running the code below, I'm still getting zero values.
The pandas version is '1.1.5', which is the version I must use.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=['male', 'female'], columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['age', 'job']]))

df['a'][['age', 'job']].loc['male'] = ['30', 'teacher']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

use tuples to access the multi-levels:

```
>>> df.loc['male', ('a', 'job')] = 'teacher'
>>> df
         a            b       c    
       age      job age job age job
male     0  teacher   0   0   0   0
female   0        0   0   0   0   0
```